# Project Reverts to Debug Every Time I Open It

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2022

I have a WPF project that I have been doing small edits to in Release mode.  It used to open up in Release mode.  Now, every time I open the project it reverts back to Debug.  What am I doing wrong?  Is VS trying to tell me something?  It's not really a big deal, but I am just wondering why this could be happening.  Thank you for any input.

Comment: Hi,@ExpertOnNothing. What is the specific version of Visual Studio 2022? And what is the Target Framework of your project? Could you show the problem with an animated screenshot and describe the steps to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio saves the last configuration (Debug or Release) that you used when working on your project.

If your project is reverting to Debug mode every time you open it, it could be due to a few reasons:

**Solution Configuration:**

Check the active solution configuration by going to the "Build" menu and selecting "Configuration Manager." Ensure that the configuration for your project is set to "Release" for the active solution configuration.
[image]
**Startup Project Configuration:**

Make sure that the startup project's configuration is set to "Release." Right-click on your solution in Solution Explorer, choose "Properties," and go to the "Startup Project" tab. Verify that the configuration for the startup project is set to "Release."
[image]
**Solution User Options:**

Visual Studio saves user-specific settings in a .suo file associated with the solution. It's possible that the .suo file is somehow corrupted or contains incorrect information. Deleting the .suo file might resolve the issue, but be aware that this will reset other user-specific settings as well.

To manually delete the .suo file:

1.Close Visual Studio.

2.Navigate to the directory where your solution is located.

3.Find the hidden .vs folder (this folder contains user-specific settings).

Inside the .vs folder, you'll find a subfolder corresponding to your solution name.-> Open it.->Delete the .suo file.

**Default Configuration:**

Ensure that you are explicitly setting the default configuration in Visual Studio. Go to the "Tools" menu, choose "Options," navigate to "Projects and Solutions" -> "Build and Run," and set the "On Run, when projects are out of date" option to "Always build."
[image]

If the issue persists, there might be a possibility of cached settings causing the problem. You can try clearing the Visual Studio cache by deleting the .vs folder in your solution directory.
After checking and adjusting these settings, restart Visual Studio and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Deleting the .suo worked.  Thank you for the very detailed explanation.  I really appreciate it.